# How to make graphs with different limits match using plotyy

Tags: matlab, plot, axes

I have two arrays that I want to plot with two axes. One using a bar-plot, and the second using regular line.

The left hand yaxis is area, and the left hand side is change in area in percent. X-axis is the date of the measurement.

My problem is that the second axis don't match the points of the bar plot. I want the points to be in the same x,y location of the plot.

```
Code:
date= [714262 724124 731733 734732 736209];      %matlab dates
area = [ 60154 48444 38991 29487 24084];         % area
area_change = [0 0.1947 0.3518 0.5098 0.5996 ];  %change in percent

figure(7)
[AX, T1, T2] = plotyy(date, area ,date, area_change, 'bar', 'line')
set(TX(2), 'ycolor', 'r')
set(TX(2),'YDir','reverse')  %% reversed to show area decrease.
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure of your question. Your corrected code matches in the date axis:

```
date= [714262 724124 731733 734732 736209];      %matlab dates
area = [ 60154 48444 38991 29487 24084];         % area
area_change = [0 0.1947 0.3518 0.5098 0.5996 ];  %change in percent

figure
[AX, T1, T2] = plotyy(date, area ,date, area_change, 'bar', 'line')
set(AX(2), 'ycolor', 'r')
set(AX(2),'YDir','reverse')
```

Or do you want the line to go through the top of the bar? If so you don't need the area_change value.

```
date= [714262 724124 731733 734732 736209];      %matlab dates
area = [ 60154 48444 38991 29487 24084];         % area
area_change = [0 0.1947 0.3518 0.5098 0.5996 ];  %change in percent

figure
bar(date, area)
hold on;
plot(date, area)
```